# How can I find where my object is being frozen?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I get this error:

```
Error: You attempted to set the key `TpDeF3wd6UoQ6BjEFmwz` with the value `{"seen":true}` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.
```

How can I discover what code is directly/indirectly freezing my object and making it immutable?

I've solved the error in development by rewriting the logic completely, but I'd like to understand how to debug this type of error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One idea it to replace `Object.freeze` with your own that logs the stack, and then calls the old freeze.

Below is an example, you can see it's at `30:8`

The line numbers in this snippet don't line up, only because SO snippets will be adding some extra wrapper code, but in production this should give you the correct line no.

```js
'use strict';

function DebugFreeze() {
  const oldFree = Object.freeze;
  Object.freeze = (...args) => {
    console.log(new Error("Object Frozen").stack);
    return oldFree.call(Object, ...args);  
  }
}

DebugFreeze();


const a = { one: 1 };

a.two = 2;

Object.freeze(a);

a.three = 3;

console.log("here");
```