# Error from firestore when subscribing to user state: TypeError: Cannot add property 2, object is not extensible

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, rxjs

I'm experimenting with firebase auth, and have encountered this error from `@firebase/utils`:

```
TypeError: Cannot add property 2, object is not extensible
```

And I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

The erroring line of code is

```
        this.observers.push(observer);
```

at the end of `ObserverProxy.subscribe`.

Up the stack a bit, this is being invoked from the `onIdTokenChanged` call in

```
function user(auth) {
    return new Observable(function (subscriber) {
        var unsubscribe = onIdTokenChanged(auth, subscriber.next.bind(subscriber), subscriber.error.bind(subscriber), subscriber.complete.bind(subscriber));
        return { unsubscribe: unsubscribe };
    });
}
```

I *think* this `user` call is from my angular `HttpInterceptor` that injects the user token onto requests, as that is the only `user` call I have so far, although with the asynchronous calls the stack trace doesn't include my code.

The interceptor does the following in `intercept`:

```
    return user(this.auth).pipe(
      switchMap(user => user?.getIdToken()),
      map(idToken =>
        !idToken
          ? req
          : req.clone({
              headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${idToken}`),
            })
      ),
      switchMap(req => next.handle(req))
    );
```

Versions:

- `node_modules/@firebase/auth/package.json`: `0.19.0`
- `node_modules/@firebase/util/package.json`: `1.4.3`

I suspect a similar question was submitted and then deleted as Google gives me a search result pointing to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70637998/firebase-auth-observer-cause-problem-with-firestore-query-observer-cant-subscri which is a deleted question. The cache doesn't show any answers on that question though.

Comment: Adding a debug operator that calls console.log for all subscribe/next/error/complete/unsubscribe to the interceptor's pipe, I see the error immediately after the subscribe, so that confirms that the issue is definitely happening in the interceptor's use of the `onIdTokenChanged` call.

Comment: With a debugger at the exception site (the expression `this.observers.push(observer);`), both `Object.isFrozen(this)` and `Object.isFrozen(this.observers)` return true. Why would these objects be frozen?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered it was ngrx freezing everything. I was passing a firebase User as an action prop, and that had some properties that gave the freezing a path into the rest of the firebase sdk and rxjs.

I found what was being frozen by replacing Object.freeze with one that would log, and eventually modified it to fail on unexpected objects being frozen, taken from

[How can I find where my object is being frozen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113473/how-can-i-find-where-my-object-is-being-frozen)

```
function DebugFreeze() {
  const oldFree = Object.freeze;
  Object.freeze = (...args) => {
    const error = new Error('Object Frozen');
    if (
      args[0] !== null &&
      typeof args[0] === 'object' &&
      Object.getPrototypeOf(args[0]) !== null &&
      args[0].constructor.name !== 'Object' &&
      args[0].constructor.name !== 'Set' &&
      args[0].constructor.name !== 'Array' &&
      args[0].constructor.name !== 'TCleanup'
    )
      throw error;
    console.log(error.stack, '\n', ...args);
    return oldFree.call(Object, ...args);
  };
}

DebugFreeze();
```

I have added a shim to convert a firebase User into a new object with a useful subset of properties when creating the action.

Comment: wow, thank you, this was the exact problem I was having, took 6+ hrs to figure out.  Added a custom user converter and everything works fine.  Specific to projects with angular, firebase, and NGRX calling auth api.  I was getting this ERROR: TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible...